# uWSGI as HTTP server: in config.ini option is called `http-socket`, not `http`

Tags: django, wsgi, uwsgi

I'm trying to use uWSGI as a standalone http server, not a uwsgi server.

Here' my configuration file `mysite.ini`:

```
[uwsgi]
chdir = /srv/workflows
module = workflows.wsgi:application
plugin = python

# We can receive connections either via http or from frontend via uwsgi socket

# http:
http = 0.0.0.0:8000

# uwsgi:
#socket = 0.0.0.0:8000
#chmod-socket = 664

vacuum = true
master = true
need-app = true
processes = 10
harakiri  = 20
max-requests = 5000
```

So, I used http option and commented-out `socket` and `chmod-socket` options.

In response to that uWSGI curses:

```
uWSGI: --s/--socket option is missing and stdin is not a socket.
```

Do I understand it right, that if I specify `socket` option, uWSGI expects connection to implement WSGI protocol? And if I specify `http` option, it expects connection to be http and I shouldn't specify the `socket` option in that case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try http-socket rather than http

Comment: Thank you, jonatron. You're right. Though, I also uncommented `plugin=python` string - it is necessary for http, too (which is logical, I guess, uWSGI itself talks to python application via WSGI).

Answer (score 2):

Official documents recommend using `http` for a public server and `http-socket` for web-server after Nginx or Apache if you want use http in network.

https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ThingsToKnow.html

Answer (score 1):

for me, HTTP works fine rather than the socket for TCP connection

example: http = 127.0.0.1:8080